# Saving bandwidth in Teams video

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want to save network bandwidth. My questions are:

- Is there a way to hide the input videos of the participants
- By minimizing the conversation in the taskbar, is Teams continue to get video stream even if they are not displayed on the screen ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the second point, but I think you can stop the video coming in - or at least in the web version of teams (if you can login to office365 online) then I have seen a button to stop the incoming video. I think it is with three dots on the right hand side... but I will try to check